# Como mostrar determinadas quantidades de linhas?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Eu tenho uma query que pega as maiores valores de venda  de determinado produto por ano . A query segue essa estrutura :

```
select ano , descricao, sum(valor) as valor from produtos 
group by descricao, ano
order by ano asc, sum(valor) desc
```

A saída segue esse estilo :

```
ano    descricao  valor
2017   produto x     999
2017   produto t     992
2017   produto c     912
2017   produto j     899
2017   produto w     799
....
2018   produto x     1999
2018   produto t     1992
2018   produto c     1912
2018   produto j     1899
2018   produto w     1799
```

Contudo eu quero apenas os 2 primeiros por ano :

```
2017   produto x     999
2017   produto t     992
2018   produto x     1999
2018   produto t     1992
```

Tem como fazer isso em uma consulta SQL usando o SQL Server ?

Comment: a minha resposta não te ajudou? poderia considerá-la como aceita?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar ROW_NUMBER () e particionar com base no ano e solicitar pela soma de valor para obter o resultado.

```sql
  select X.ano, X.descricao, X.valor from 
       (select ano, descricao, valor, 
               row_number() over (
                 partition by ano order by valor desc
               ) rank_of_count
         from (
           select ano, descricao, sum(valor) valor 
           from produtos group by ano, descricao
         ) p
       ) X
 where rank_of_count <= 2
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1c235/49

Comment: Excelente solução. Deu certo, obrigado.